# A tight upper bound on this Binomial sum

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, convergence-divergence, combinations, binomial-coefficients

I have the following function:
$P(n)=q^n\sum\limits_{H=0}^{n-1}{{H+n-1\choose H}w^H}+w^n\sum\limits_{H=n}^{\infty}{{H+n-1\choose H}q^H}$, where $0<q<0.5<w<1$ and $q+w=1$.

My end goal is to prove that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $k$ such that: $S(k) = \sum\limits_{n=k}^{\infty}{P(n)}<\epsilon$.
I have an intuition that it holds, based on numerical calculation and because of the nature of the problem it describes.

So far I tried to use Stirling's bound on $P(n)$, but it wasn't tight enough for $S(k)$.
When I used Mathematica in order to calculate $P(n)$ explicitly, I got a complicated expression with the Hypergeometric 2F1 function.
Although I could use that to try to bound $S(k)$, I'm looking for a cleaner solution, that would allow me to bound $P(n)$, so that I don't have to calculate $S(k)$ explicitly to get a bound.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question to provide additional information.

Comment: Let $a_H = \binom {H + n - 1} H$, then
$$\sum_{0 \leq H < n} a_H w^H \leq
n a_{n - 1} w^{n - 1}$$
because $a_H w_H$ is increasing, and
$$\sum_{H \geq n} a_H q^H \leq
a_n q^n \sum_{H \geq n} (2 q)^{H - n}$$
because $a_{H + 1} q^{H + 1}/(a_H q^H) \leq 2 q$. Since $4 q w < 1$, it follows that $\sum_n P(n)$ converges, so the tail tends to zero.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It took me time to make the transitions myself, but it works! Specifically, I had to use the following inequality: ${2n \choose n} < {4^n}\cdot {(\pi n)^{-0.5}}$.